# Replacing Variables Containing Newlines in macOS Terminal

Tags: macos, sed

I'm trying to replace the content of a variable consisting newlines in macOS Terminal but this error or some other errors show up:

```
echo $index | sed "s/{{content_2}}/$side/g"
```

outputs:

```
sed: 1: "s/{{content_2}}/<div cl ...": unescaped newline inside
```

substitute pattern

This is $index:

```
{{navbar}} {{content_10}} {{content_2}} {{footer}}
```

This is $side:

```
 <div class="col-md-2"><div class="content" id="contentAside"><h5 class="text-uppercase pt-3">Aside</h5><div class="card" style="width: 18rem;"><img class="card-img-top" src="img/card.jpg" alt="Card image cap"><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5><p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p><hr><p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p><hr><p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p><hr><p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p><hr><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I just put it, can you take a look at it?

Comment: There are obvious problems with your script but there no newlines in your sample input variables (what you specifically asked about) and you haven't provided the expected output so fix both of those situations if you'd like help.

Comment: in my original file there are new lines